# Highcharts broken in IE when called page via AJAX - Exception with jQuery

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, highcharts

I seem to be having an Issue with IE which loads the page via AJAX. We use jQuery, Bootstrap, Select2 and Highcharts and not sure if its an issue caused by Select2 ajax call but the no-results code seems to be fine with the AJAX return.
Im getting a jQuery Exception when there is no highcharts it seems to be fine so im not sure where the issue is...

http://jsfiddle.net/koconder/2aXem/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#country').select2();
    $('#keyword').select2();
    $('#device').select2();

    //$('#keyword').select2('val', 'NULL').select2('disable');
    //$('#device').select2('val', 'NULL').select2('disable');

    $('#app').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        placeholder: {
            title: "Select your app...",
            id: ""
        },
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://dev.adtrafik.com/static/t/ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    term: term, // search term
                    page_limit: 10,
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            }

        },
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            return $.getJSON('http://dev.adtrafik.com/static/t/ajax/select2_sample.php?post=3&id=' + (element.val()), null, function (data) {
                return callback(data);
            });
        }
    });
    $('#app').select2('data', {
        id: '48',
        text: 'Free Poker by PokerStars'
    })//.select2('disable')

    $('#country').change(function () {
        var id = $('#country').val();
        var dataString = 'post=1&id1=' + id;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://dev.adtrafik.com/static/t/ajax.php',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                //$('#device').select2('enable');
                $('#device').html(html);
                $('#keyword').html('');
            }
        });
    });
    $('#device').change(function () {
        var id = $('#country').val();
        var id2 = $('#device').val();
        var dataString = 'post=2&id1=' + id + '&id2=' + id2;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://dev.adtrafik.com/static/t/ajax.php',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                //$('#keyword').select2('enable');
                $('#keyword').html(html);
            }
        });
    });
    $('#keyword').change(function () {
       // $('#app').select2('enable');
    });
    $('#go').click(function (event) {
        var id = $('#country').val();
        var id2 = $('#device').val();
        var id3 = $('#keyword').val();
        var id4 = $('#app').val();
        var dataString = 'post=4&regionid=' + id + '&engineid=' + id2 + '&kwid=' + id3 + '&appid=' + id4;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://dev.adtrafik.com/static/t/ajax.php',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#chart').fadeOut(function () {
                    $('#chart').html(html).fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It says some issue exeption with jQuery along with Series Options is null which isint true and tried my best to debug via IE (painnfull!!!)

I cant load the same AJAX via jFiddle but the code is there....
Im happy to pay a few squids for help :).

Vincent

Comment: Too much code. What exactly isn't working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: ajax call which results highcharts js is broken, so you get a JS error and nothing works in IE

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/514

Issue found, IE bug with ending ',' in data series and variables.